# Is it possible to apply single lines from stash?

Tags: git, git-stash, git-stage, git-index, tig

I'm looking for a way to include specific parts of stashes in stage. I'm using TIG frontend, so the method can involve some low level offset, etc. calculation. However currently I don't have any idea of what to compute.

Does someone have an idea of how to move single lines from a stash into the stage area?

Answer (score 3):

Try difftool against stash

```
git difftool stash@{0}
```

This will open a difftool (Kdiff3 in my case) and than you will be able to merge files and select willing lines.

Comment: Worth mentioning : [`git difftool -d`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-difftool#Documentation/git-difftool.txt--d) (short for `git difftool --dir-diff`) will set up a "directory comparison" mode.

Comment: That's interesting... If not the pain of coming up with and choosing any diff tool. Any recommendations? Kdiff3 is not possible as I don't have kdelibs in my system...

Comment: https://www.tecmint.com/best-linux-file-diff-tools-comparison/ Here is good comparison of dozen of Diff tools.